# exception handling task parallel

Tags: .net, task-parallel-library

I wont get the the aggregate exception is not getting executed

```
namespace ExceptionTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Task<int> t1 = new Task<int>(() => Add());
            try
            {
                t1.Start();
            }
            catch (AggregateException ag)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ag.Message);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        static int Add()
        {
            try
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("Exception");
            }
            catch(Exception e) { throw e; }

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[`Start()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd270682) will never throw in a situation like this. It only starts the `Task`, and immediately returns; it doesn't wait until the `Task` completes.

If you want to catch the exception, you should use [`Wait()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd235635):

```
Task<int> t1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Add());
try
{
    t1.Wait();
}
catch (AggregateException ag)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ag.Message);
}
```

And if you use `Wait()`, you can use `Task.Factory.StartNew()` (or `Task.Run()` on .Net 4.5) instead of constructor with `Start()`. And you also don't need `Console.ReadLine()` anymore. (Both changes reflected in the above code.)

Comment: Also calling to `Task` `Result` will re-throw exception if it thrown earlier in `Task` execution.